# Return Value On Form Submission in Rails w/ Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

So here's what I want to do.

1. User fills in the form (Just a textbox and submit)
2. The record is added in the background
3. The created record's ID is returned
4. A URL (based on the ID) is displayed

How could I go about achieving something like this? Does anyone have any reading material which would help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any [scaffold](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running-quickly-with-scaffolding) will provide you with almost all the code you need to achieve this.

Then add `:remote => true` to the form and change slightly the flash message to display `resource_name_path(@resource)`